# Error :found a dependency cycle

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to inject `ItemRepository` which depends on `RemoteDataSource` and `LocalDataSource`.
I spent a lot of time to resolve the problem, but no luck.

```
 Error:(26, 10) error: Found a dependency cycle:
com.project.bishoy.lost.data.ItemsRepository is injected at
com.project.bishoy.lost.di.modules.ApplicationModule.provideItemsRepository(itemsRepository)
com.project.bishoy.lost.data.ItemsRepository is injected at
com.project.bishoy.lost.LostApp.mItemsRepository
com.project.bishoy.lost.LostApp is injected at
com.project.bishoy.lost.di.components.ApplicationComponent.inject(lostApp)
Error:(34, 21) error: Found a dependency cycle:
com.project.bishoy.lost.data.local.LocalDataSource is injected at
com.project.bishoy.lost.di.modules.ApplicationModule.provideLocalDataSource(localDataSource)
com.project.bishoy.lost.data.local.LocalDataSource is provided at
com.project.bishoy.lost.di.components.ApplicationComponent.getLocalDataSource()
Error:(36, 22) error: Found a dependency cycle:
com.project.bishoy.lost.data.remote.RemoteDataSource is injected at
com.project.bishoy.lost.di.modules.ApplicationModule.provideRemoteDataSource(remoteDataSource)
com.project.bishoy.lost.data.remote.RemoteDataSource is provided at
com.project.bishoy.lost.di.components.ApplicationComponent.getRemoteDataSource()
Error:(38, 21) error: Found a dependency cycle:
com.project.bishoy.lost.data.ItemsRepository is injected at
com.project.bishoy.lost.di.modules.ApplicationModule.provideItemsRepository(itemsRepository)
com.project.bishoy.lost.data.ItemsRepository is provided at
com.project.bishoy.lost.di.components.ApplicationComponent.getDataManager()
```

**ApplicationModule.java**

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

 private final Application mApplication;

 public ApplicationModule(Application app) {
  mApplication = app;
 }

 @Provides
 @ApplicationContext
 Context provideContext() {
  return mApplication;
 }

 @Provides
 Application provideApplication() {
  return mApplication;
 }


 @Provides
 @Singleton
 RemoteDataSource provideRemoteDataSource(RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource) {
  return remoteDataSource;
 }

 @Provides
 @Singleton
 LocalDataSource provideLocalDataSource(LocalDataSource localDataSource) {
  return localDataSource;
 }

 @Singleton
 @Provides
 ItemsRepository provideItemsRepository(ItemsRepository itemsRepository) {
  return itemsRepository;
 }
}
```

**ApplicationComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

 void inject(LostApp lostApp);

 Application getApplication();

 @ApplicationContext
 Context getContext();

 LocalDataSource getLocalDataSource();
 RemoteDataSource getRemoteDataSource();
 ItemsRepository getDataManager();
}
```

Comment: you are trying to provide `LocalDataSource` to `LocalDataSource`. That is impossible. You cannot add a dependency of the same class that you are trying to instanciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have simple constructors on `RemoteDataSource.java` and `LocalDataSource.java` with no arguments and you have a constructor that receives both local and remote data sources in `ItemRepository.java`, your code would look something like this:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

 private final Application mApplication;

 public ApplicationModule(Application app) {
  mApplication = app;
 }

 @Provides
 @ApplicationContext
 Context provideContext() {
  return mApplication;
 }

 @Provides
 Application provideApplication() {
  return mApplication;
 }

 @Provides
 @Singleton
 RemoteDataSource provideRemoteDataSource() {
  return new RemoteDataSource();
 }

 @Provides
 @Singleton
 LocalDataSource provideLocalDataSource() {
  return new LocalDataSource();
 }

 @Singleton
 @Provides
 ItemsRepository provideItemsRepository(LocalDataSource localDataSource, RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource) {
  return new ItemsRepository(localDataSource, remoteDataSource);
 }
}
```